# Proving: $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{\sin ^2\pi x}-\frac1{x^2}\right)=\frac{\pi ^2}3$ without L'Hospital

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluating
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{\sin ^2\pi x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
with L'Hospital is so tedious. Does anyone know a way to evaluate the limit without using L'Hospital? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Do the subtraction and replace denominator by $\pi^2x^4$. Factorize numerator and express as a product of two suitable fractions. Done!!

Comment: Whenever you want to use L'Hospital's Rule, first try a little algebraic manipulation to transform the expression in a form which makes application of L'Hospital's Rule simple and useful. Also avoid its repeated applications. For example here just a single application of L'Hospital's Rule suffices.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the denominator"?

Comment: When you subtract you will get an expression with denominator $x^2 \sin^2\pi x$. Now replace this denominator with $\pi^2x^4$ via the use of $\lim_{t\to 0}(\sin t) /t=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Maclaurin expansion we get:
$$
\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}
= \frac{\pi x - \frac16 (\pi x)^3 + O(x^5)}{\pi x}
= 1 - \frac{\pi^2 x^2}{6} + O(x^4)
\\
\frac{\pi x}{\sin\pi x} = 1 + \frac{\pi^2 x^2}{6} + O(x^4) 
\\
\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sin\pi x}\right)^2 = 1 + \frac{\pi^2 x^2}{3} + O(x^4) 
\\
\frac{\pi ^2}{\sin ^2\pi x}-\frac{1}{x^2}
= \frac{1}{x^2}\left[\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sin\pi x}\right)^2-1\right]
= \frac{\pi^2}{3} + O(x^2)
\to \frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$

Comment: How did you get the expansion for $\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\right)^2$ from the expansion for $\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}$?

Comment: If $u(t) = a + bt + O(t^2)$ then $u(t)^2 = (a + bt + O(t^2))^2 = a^2 + 2abt + O(t^2).$

Comment: That follows from $\frac{1}{1-t} = 1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots=1+t+O(t^2).$

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've got your answer, and it's a good one, I'd use series expansions *always* in such case, but then, the answerer couldn't know you've ever heard of those expansions, and some of your comments show you aren't too familiar with them. That's why SE encourages sharing information about your mathematical background, btw. Most people ignore that. But then, you risk to get an answer like the following, without any l'Hospitals, based only on elementary principles:

"From the elementary identity
$$\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac1{x^2}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}3^{-2k}\,\frac{\frac83-\frac{16}9\sin^2\frac{x}{3^k}}{\left(1-\frac43\sin^2 \frac{x}{3^k}\right)^2},$$ letting $x\to0,$ we get $$\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac1{x^2}\to\sum^\infty_{k=1}3^{-2k}\cdot\frac83=\frac13,$$ and the result we're looking for follows after replacing $x\to\pi x.$"

The joke is: that identity is an elementary consequence of the triplication formula $$\sin3y=3\sin y-4\sin^3y$$ and the limit $\sin y/y\to1$ as $y\to0,$ indeed.

Of course, such an answer isn't helpful, not just because it is rather obscure, but also because the method is applicable only in exceptional cases.

Comment: The value of this answer lies not just in the method (middle part) but more importantly in the opening and closing remarks. +1

Answer (score 2):

**Pre-Calculus Answer to the Question**

Note that since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), and $\frac1x$ is continuous at $x=1$, we also have $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac x{\sin(x)}=1$.
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi x)}-\frac1{x^2}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\pi^2x^2-\sin^2(\pi x)}{x^2\sin^2(\pi x)}\tag{1a}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\pi x-\sin(\pi x)}{(\pi x)^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\pi x+\sin(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\pi^2(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
&=\frac16\cdot2\cdot\pi^2\tag{1c}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi^2}3\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: algebra
$\text{(1b)}$: factorization
$\text{(1c)}$: apply $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac x{\sin(x)}=1$ from above
$\phantom{\text{(1c):}}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac16$ from below
$\text{(1d)}$: computation

---

**Proof that $\boldsymbol{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac16}$**

Assume that $0\lt x\le\frac\pi3$. Then, $\cos(x)\ge\frac12$ and $0\le\sin(x)\le x\le\tan(x)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}
&\le\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac1{\cos(x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{4\,(x/2)^2}\tag{2c}\\[6pt]
&\le1\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}-\frac14\frac{x/2-\sin(x/2)}{(x/2)^3}\tag{3a}\\
&=\frac{2(x/2)-2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}{8(x/2)^3}-\frac{2(x/2)-2\sin(x/2)}{8(x/2)^3}\tag{3b}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(x/2)(1-\cos(x/2))}{8(x/2)^3}\tag{3c}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(x/2)\,2\sin^2(x/4)}{8(x/2)^3}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$, $(3)$ shows that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}-\frac14\frac{x/2-\sin(x/2)}{(x/2)^3}\right)=\frac18\tag4
$$
For any $n$, adding $\frac1{4^k}$ times $(4)$ with $x\mapsto x/2^k$ for $k$ from $0$ to $n-1$  gives
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}-\frac1{4^n}\frac{x/2^n-\sin\left(x/2^n\right)}{\left(x/2^n\right)^3}\right)
&=\frac18\frac{1-(1/4)^n}{1-1/4}\tag{5a}\\
&=\frac16-\frac16\frac1{4^n}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for any $\epsilon\gt0$, choose $n$ large enough so that $\frac1{4^n}\le\frac\epsilon2$. Then, $(5)$ says that we can choose a $\delta\gt0$ so that if $0\lt x\le\delta$,
$$
\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}-\overbrace{\frac1{4^n}\frac{x/2^n-\sin\left(x/2^n\right)}{\left(x/2^n\right)^3}}^{\frac12[0,\epsilon]_\#}
=\frac16-\!\overbrace{\ \ \ \frac16\frac1{4^n}\ \ \ }^{\frac1{12}[0,\epsilon]_\#}\!+\frac12[-\epsilon,\epsilon]_\#\tag6
$$
where $[a,b]_\#$ represents a number between $a$ and $b$. The bounds above the braces follow from $(2)$ and the choice of $n$.

Equation $(6)$ says that for $0\lt x\le\delta$,
$$
\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac16+[-\epsilon,\epsilon]_\#\tag7
$$
Since $\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}$ is even, we can say that $(7)$ is true for $0\lt|x|\le\delta$, which means that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac16\tag8
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach: as it's an even function, assume $x>0$. Cut a sector in a radius-$\sqrt{2}$ angle subtending $\pi x$ radians at the centre so $\pi x-\sin\pi x$ is the area in the sector outside the triangle with the same vertices. We'll approximate the arc as a parabola, in Cartesian coordinates with the line segment of the same endpoints a part of the $X$-axis, with extrema at $X=\pm\sqrt{2}\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}\sim\pm\frac{\pi x}{\sqrt{2}}$. The peak is at$$X=0,\,Y=\sqrt{2}(1-\cos\frac{\pi x}{2})=2\sqrt{2}\sin^2\frac{\pi x}{4}\sim\frac{\pi^2x^2\sqrt{2}}{8}.$$At leading order, the parabola is $Y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(\pi^2x^2/2-X^2)$, so the area below it is$$\int_{-\pi x/\sqrt{2}}^{\pi x/\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(\pi^2x^2/2-X^2)dX=\frac{\pi^3x^3}{6}.$$So for small $x$,$$\pi x-\sin\pi x\sim\frac{\pi^3x^3}{6}\implies\frac{1}{\sin\pi x}-\frac{1}{\pi x}\sim\frac{\pi^2x^2}{6\sin\pi x}\sim\frac{\pi x}{6}\implies\frac{1}{\sin^2\pi x}-\frac{1}{\pi^2x^2}\sim\frac{\pi x}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\pi x}=\frac13.$$